# Is the use of "that when" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

For example:

> Henry Fayol figured out **that when** a worker is assigned one
>   specific task of one specific subject, he execute it faster instead of
>   he execute of different subjects in equal quantities of tasks.

Comment: The sentence has multiple grammatical mistakes, for example, "execute" should be either "executed" or "executes" and "instead of" should not be there. What's the source of this sentence?

Comment: HF figured out that if a worker is assigned one specific task of one specific kind, he executes it faster than if he were assigned several tasks of several kinds.   Still not good, but better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It becomes correct when a comma (,) is placed after "that".

"Henry Fayol figured out that **,**  when a worker is assigned [to] one specific task of one specific subject, he [will] execute it faster instead....."